# CSS drop down menu :hover state doesnt seem to work

Tags: html, css

I tried to make a drop down menu using css and the :hover state, but the submenu doesn't drop down when I hover over the first `<li>`
Can someone help me?

[jsfiddle.net/mpo2fq5z](http://jsfiddle.net/mpo2fq5z)

Here is my html:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>Menu</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Submenu</li>
            <li>Submenu</li>
            <li>Submenu</li>
        </ul>
        <li>Menu</li>
        <li>Menu</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the accompanying CSS:

```
body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:18px;
    color:red;
}
#menu {
    background-color:#222;
}
#menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#menu ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:15px;
}
#menu ul li:hover {
    background-color:black;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
#menu ul ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#333;
    min-width:200px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-top:15px;
    padding:0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your selector says #menu ul li:hover ul. That states that your sub menu is inside the

element, although it is not. To fix that, simply insert the second  inside the

```
<li>Menu
    <ul>
        <li>Submenu</li>
        <li>Submenu</li>
        <li>Submenu</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I also updated your JsFiddle with the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this html, put ul inside li so it works as its child.

```
<div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li>Menu
                    <ul>
                        <li>Submenu</li>
                        <li>Submenu</li>
                        <li>Submenu</li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                <li>Menu</li>
                <li>Menu</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpo2fq5z/8/)